# Grails classpath issues: Using Grails with newer versions of libraries in the Grails distribution

Tags: grails, maven, classpath

Grails 2.0.x ships with about a hundred third-party JARs -- ant, AspectJ, various things from Apache Commons, and so on. This is... good, I suppose?

But I want to use newer versions of some of those JARs, and when I try, I get various compatibility issues -- e.g., if I write a test using a Hamcrest class that was new in 1.2, I can, but at runtime I get NoSuchMethodErrors because the 1.1 Hamcrest core is ahead of it in the classpath.

I could of course just start messing with the grails-2.0.x/lib directory, but this seems like a bad idea and also means bypassing the normal Ivy / Maven way of specifying dependencies. (Oh, additional wrinkle: I'm using Maven for my Grails app, for interoperability with the rest of our codebase.)

So am I stuck with the Grails-distributed versions of these third-party JARs, or is there some way out of this?

Comment: Maybe it's a scope problem? If I don't say <scope>test</scope> for Hamcrest, it works. It would be nice to know what's really going on.

Comment: I think trying to upgrade the libraries grails depends on will cause various compatibility issues - you probably have to stick to what grails already has